# Why don't I get Views?

Tags: android, view, progressdialog

I have the next code

```
     ProgressDialog pd;
 LinearLayout layout;
 ListView listview;
 TextView name[];
 TextView website[];
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main); 
       pd = ProgressDialog.show(this,
               "Title",
               "Message",
               true, false);

       new Thread(new Runnable(){
           public void run(){
           begin();
           pd.dismiss();
           }
           }).start();







    }




public void begin(){       
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 

    String dia2,mes2;
    mes2="0";
   int dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
   int mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); 




    try {

    URL url = new URL(
    "http://www.tudiscovery.com/dni-tvlistings/GetScheduleByBroadcastDate?type=day&country_code=LTM&channel_code=DCLA-SP&date="+ dia2 +""+ mes2 +"2012");



    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("programme");

    /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
    name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
    website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];


    for (int i = 0; i <= nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

    Node node = nodeList.item(i);

    name[i] = new TextView(this);
    website[i] = new TextView(this);


    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("series-title");
    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

    name[i].setText("Programa = "
    + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

    NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("raw");
    Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
    websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
    website[i].setText("Hora = "
    + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue().subSequence(0, 2) +":" + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue().subSequence(2, 4));


    name[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
    name[i].setTextSize(12);
   layout.addView(name[i]);
    layout.addView(website[i]);



    } 


    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

when i want to get the View I got this error: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

anybody have a solution for this code?

PSD: this is a rss parse

Comment: google translate + "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." ... you can't do UI operation on NON UI thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant update the UI on the a seperate thread. You only can update it on the Main thread

```
 new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
       begin();
       pd.dismiss();
       }
       }).start();
```

For this you should use an [AsnycTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It has methods that allow you to update the main UI while doing background work, or after or before it is complete.

Comment: @JoséFranciscoLaraAguilar: And the `pd.dismiss()` is only part of the problem. You've also got lines like `layout.addView(name[i])`. As mentioned, all UI code has to be kept on the UI thread and AsyncTask is the best way to go. I also found [this explanation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) helpful.

Comment: What did you try? Post an edit in your answer. It should work

Comment: I Think that I can´t manipulate the views that has Created by the begin() function, and when I Run the code, i Got The progressDialog perfectly, but the Views are not loaded, and its shows a BlackScreen Only

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are missing a step.

Comment: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views anybody have a Idea for this error: **Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views**

Comment: thanks @coder_For_Life22 I am Panamenian and I speak spanish as Own Lenguage, is probaly that my lenguage is the problem an I don´t Understand it. Thanks you so much